# Access Error Language - Error '-2147319779 (8002801d)' in the execution time

Tags: ms-access, vba, runtime-error

I have a function that checks whether the excel configuration is in English or Spanish to set the name of the spreadsheet.

```
Public Function VersionExcel(ByVal appxls As excel.Application) As String

   Dim Hoja1 As String

   'Si aplicacion en ingles

    If (appxls.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(1) = 1033) Then

        Hoja1 = "Sheet1"

    Else

        Hoja1 = "Hoja1"

    End If

    VersionExcel = Hoja1

End Function
```

It has been working for almost 10 years, but lately I have been getting this error when executing that code:

[Code Stop] https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGgvh.jpg

[Error message] https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfgNZ.jpg

> "Error '-2147319779 (8002801d)' in the execution time. 
>   Method 'LanguageSettings' error for the object '_Application'"

In certain PCs works and in others don´t. What can be wrong with the configuration of the Excel to get this error?

I have already checked that the references are the same. But I am kinda getting crazy with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a Late / Early Binding issue. 
If your users have different versions of Access and the version this is developed/compiled  in is a later version then early binding the object reference won't work.

Review https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/245115/using-early-binding-and-late-binding-in-automation for more assistance